# How to call this.function within setTimeout in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS:

```
function TrackTime() {

    this.CountBack = function(secs) {
        setTimeout(function(){this.CountBack(secs)}, SetTimeOutPeriod);
    }

}
```

I have tried this with a closure (seen above) and also about a dozen other ways. I can't seem to get this to work in any browser. The setTimeout function works fine when not being called in a "class" function. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because of the change in the scope of "this" when the function is executed.

Try that-this trick..

```
    function TrackTime() {  
        this.CountBack = function(secs) {         
            var that = this;

            setTimeout(function(){that.CountBack(secs)}, SetTimeOutPeriod);     
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var that = this;
this.CountBack = function (secs) {
    setTimeout(function () {that.CountBack(secs)}, SetTimeOutPeriod);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your not able to use closures here is because setTimeout runs off the window object, so 'this' is always 'window'. You'll want to use a partial function application here to set the context (and optionally some predefined parameters!) of your function *while* keeping it as a reference, so it can be used as event handler! Neat eh? See below.

```
// This will call a function using a reference with predefined arguments.
function partial(func, context /*, 0..n args */) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return function() {
    var allArguments = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    return func.apply(context ? context : this, allArguments);
  };
}
```